# Enumeration and class reference

Tags: c#, reference, enums

I started learning C sharp from Andrew Tolson's *Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework, 6th Edition* a few days back and as a Java Programmer, many concepts have embezzled me regarding the **Type** concept in C sharp.
I was reading enumeration in C sharp and I saw the type hierarchy of System. Basically, author has said that the enumerations are extended from **System.ValueType** abstract class. From this I inferred **enum** is nothing but an extension of the class **ValueType**. I also examined the IL for an **enum** and it was something like this:

```
.class private auto ansi sealed TestPrograms.EmpType
   extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
} // end of class TestPrograms.EmpType
.field public static literal valuetype TestPrograms.EmpType Contractor = uint8(0x64)
//...and so on for other literals
```

for the following **enum**,

```
enum EmpType : byte
    {
    Manager = 10,
    Grunt = 1,
    Contractor = 100,
    VicePresident = 9
    }
```

Now here is the thing - Since **EmpType** is a class extension of **System.Enum**, writing the following should mean a class reference,

```
EmpType emp;
```

My first question is as follows:
Why do we initialize this reference as,

```
EmpType emp = EmpType.Contractor;
```

And my second question is, if I pass this reference as a method argument, the resulting behavior is "Call by Value", i.e, if I write the following code:

```
class EmpTypeTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**** Fun with Enums *****");
        EmpType emp = EmpType.Contractor;
        AskForBonus(emp);
        Console.WriteLine((byte)emp);
        // Prints out "emp is a Contractor".
        Console.WriteLine("emp is a {0}.", emp.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AskForBonus(EmpType e)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case EmpType.Manager:
                Console.WriteLine("How about stock options instead?");
                break;
            case EmpType.Grunt:
                Console.WriteLine("You have got to be kidding...");
                break;
            case EmpType.Contractor:
                Console.WriteLine("You already get enough cash...");
                e++;
                Console.WriteLine((byte)e);
                break;
            case EmpType.VicePresident:
                Console.WriteLine("VERY GOOD, Sir!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

there is no change in the value of emp. Why isn't the "Call by reference" behavior supported?

Comment: As for the "call by reference" part, _all_ parameter passing in C# is "call by value" unless `ref` or `out` are specified. Please do not conflate passing a reference by value with passing "by reference". They are not the same.

Comment: @PeterDuniho : Yeah, I read the answer and now what I still want to ask is, see my comment to Christos' answer

Comment: `EmpType` is not a reference type. It is a value type. You need to read the [Ecma-335 CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). All types that inherit from `System.ValueType` that are not `System.Enum` and `System.Enum` are value types. You are infering something from the decompiled IL that is simply not true.

Comment: @mikez : Ecma-335 CLI specification? Hmm...I knew the moment would come. The reason I had held off was, I started C sharp 5 days ago and am still going through the Core language constructs. So, I would read it after spending some more time with the language. But thanks for recommending

Comment: @mikez : Anyway mike, can ya tell me, which language part is reponsible for rendering the ValueType behavior to an enum? ValueType is just an abstract class with no other interface implementation

Comment: @pulp_fiction in C# the two ways to declare value type are using the `struct` and and `enum` keywords. The compiler transforms those into types that inherit from `System.ValueType` and `System.Enum`, respectively. You cannot not inherit from those types directly. For the purposes of learning the language, just take it as a given that that is how you declare value types.

Comment: Also as to the decompiled IL, the spec has this to say of type declarations which are called "class headers" in the spec:  For historical reasons, many of the syntactic categories used for defining types incorrectly use “class” instead of “type” in their name. All classes are types, but “types” is a broader term encompassing value types, and interfaces as well.

Comment: "I started C sharp 5 days ago" -- FWIW I'd say that at this point in your learning, you would be much better served by reading the [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) on MSDN, including the sections on ["value types"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and ["reference types"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), than to worry about specific implementation details. You may also find [Difference Between Passing a Struct and...a Class Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx) useful

Comment: @PeterDuniho: You are right perhaps. But I am able to move forward through this book because of my Java background. Java's key language features and facilities are similar to C sharp. There are a few major differences and few minor ones here and there. Nevertheless, it has helped me a lot of things.

Comment: Java is similar. Just similar enough to _really_ confuse people at least some of the time. For example, `enum` in Java is significantly different from `enum` in C#. :)